# How to get datasource from Connectionstring using PowerShell?

Tags: sql, .net, powershell

In .Net we can get the datasource from a connectionstring using below mechanism:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string server = builder.DataSource;
```

I was trying to do that in PowerShell but getting the following exception:

```
$ConstringObj = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder($conString)
```

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Keyword
>   not supported: 'metadata'." At line:1 char:17
>   + $ConstringObj = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder($con ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

How to do that in PowerShell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solutions

#### Option A - Use Dictionary Names

You can use the bracket or dot notation with the actual sql key to access the entry in the [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7)

```cs
$cnnBuilder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$cnnBuilder["Data Source"] = "server_name"
$cnnBuilder."Initial Catalog" = "db_name"
```

#### Option B - Use `PSBase`

`PSBase` returns the [*"raw view of the object"*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/whats-up-with-psbase-psextended-psadapted-and-psobject/) and will give us the default behavior in dotnet

```cs
$cnnBuilder  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$cnnBuilder.PSBase.DataSource = "server_name"
$cnnBuilder.PSBase.InitialCatalog = "db_name"
```

#### Option C - Use `-Property` Parameter

During the construction, you can set the [`-Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter on `New-Object` which *"sets property values and invokes methods of the new object."*

```cs
$cnnBuilder  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder `
    -Property @{
        DataSource = "server_name"
        InitialCatalog = "db_name"
    }
```

### Explanation

There's some weird behavior when using [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in PowerShell - let me explain

Since it's a dotnet class, you'd expect all of the same properties and methods available in C#

For example, this works fine in C#:

```cs
var cnnBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
cnnBuilder.DataSource = "server_name";
cnnBuilder.InitialCatalog = "db_name";
```

So the equivalent code in PS, *should* work:

```cs
$cnnBuilder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$cnnBuilder.DataSource = "server_name"
$cnnBuilder.InitialCatalog = "db_name"
```

However, `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is built on top of [`DbConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) which implements [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=netcore-3.1) so fundamentally we're working with a dictionary object that has some syntactic sugar wrappers

.NET resolves this with an [override on the dictionary accessors and setters](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/4.6.2/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs#L250) like this (simplified here):

```cs
public override object this[string keyword] {
    get {
        Keywords index = GetIndex(keyword);
        return GetAt(index);
    }
    set {
        Keywords index = GetIndex(keyword);
        switch(index) {
            case Keywords.DataSource: DataSource = ConvertToString(value); break;
            case Keywords.InitialCatalog: InitialCatalog = ConvertToString(value); break;
            // ***
        }
    }
}
```

So really, it's taking the [`DataSource` property and mapping it to the `"Data Source"` key](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/4.6.2/System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbConnectionStringCommon.cs#L963) <sup>(*with space*)</sup>

```cs
internal static class DbConnectionStringKeywords {
    internal const string DataSource = "Data Source";
}
```

Whenever PS assigns or retrieves a value, it has to decide whether to use the underlying dictionary implementation or the property.  And when you look for `DataSource` in the dictionary (without the space), that [sql connection keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't exist.

### Additional Reading

- [Using SQLConnection object in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/q/453531/180163)

Answer (score 3):

Your example should work. However, you could also grab the datasource using a regex:

```
[regex]::Match($ConstringObj, 'Data Source=([^;]+)').Groups[1].Value
```